# How can I start a background job in Powershell that outlives it's parent?

Tags: powershell

Consider the following code:

```
start-job -scriptblock { sleep 10; cmd /c set > c:\env.txt; }
exit
```

The background job is killed when the parent exits, so the call to cmd.exe never occurs. I would like to write some similar code, such that the parent exits immediately, and the child continues to run in the background.

I would like to keep everything in one script if possible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will have to start a process:

```
start-process powershell -ArgumentList "sleep 10; cmd /c set > c:\env.txt" -WindowStyle hidden
```

Answer (score 25):

If you use Start-Process, you create a new child process that has your powershell session as its parent process. If you kill the powershell parent *process* that starts this, the new process will be orphaned and keep running. It will, however, not survive if you kill the parent's *process tree*

```
Start-Process -FilePath notepad.exe
```

Powershell cannot start a new independent process outside of its process tree for you. However, this can be done in Windows using *CreateProcess* and this functionality is exposed through WMI. Luckily, you can call that from powershell:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList notepad.exe
```

This way, the new process will also keep running if the *process tree* is killed, because the new process does not have your powershell session as a parent, but the WMI host process.

Comment: Wow, thanks a zillion times, and +1. That answer just helped me solve a hairy problem after two days of unsuccessful debugging and testing.

Comment: Any way to pass arguments to the exe? Edit: -ArgumentList 'notepad.exe --environment test' works for me.

Answer (score 4):

If found that using Invoke-Command was able to bypass the restriction that the background job dies with it's parent. The nice thing is that the syntax is almost the same as with start-job, so the scriptblock can be kept as is.

```
start-job -scriptblock { sleep 10; cmd /c set > c:\env.txt; }
```

would just turn into

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -AsJob -scriptblock { sleep 10; cmd /c set > c:\env.txt; }
```

and suddenly survive the death of it's parent (probably because invoke-command is fit to run programs on another computer so the parent can never matter to it)

Comment: It seems [Invoke-Command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347578.aspx) requires [remote requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements?view=powershell-6) also for local operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like that

```
$a = start-job -scriptblock { sleep 10; cmd /c set > c:\env.txt; }
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $a -EventName StateChanged -SourceIdentifier "finished"
$b = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier "finished"
exit
```

Your script will wait for the end of the scriptblock to finish.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as using Wait-job?

Comment: What I was trying to say was, I don't think the OP wants that. What they want is that the job still run when the parent closes ( and should close) but should not be waiting for the job. But I might be wrong in this :)

Comment: I don't know, in fact I don't mind, I just give another way, and Wait-job is shorter, it can help somebody else.