# How to spawn a powershell script or executable that is independent of current process?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am currently using `Pipeline` and `PowerShell` to spawn a separate executable PowerShell script, with the help of `Command`.  Currently, I am invoking the executable from my original process asynchronously.

What I want to do is be able to allow the script or executable that I spawn to run independently of the current process.  That way the script can kill the process that spawned it, without also dying.  The behavior that I am experiencing right now is that when the script is run and it kills the process that spawned it, it too dies.

How can I spawn the secondary executable to be entirely independent so the process that spawned it can be killed, yet its execution will continue?

Comment: You could look into `Start-Job`, it will start a new independent console running a script block

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8515359/26396

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Disconnect-PSSession` to disconnect your main process that spawned the job from the job session.

The job will continue to run, and you can use `Connect-PSSession` from another PowerShell session later to re-connect to the session and receive the job data.

[Remote Disconnected Sessions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149006.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I'm a little confused by "Disconnet-PSSession"'s parameters.  All I want to do is disconnect the current script from the session that spawns it, so I put "Disconnect-PSSession" in to the script, but then it asks me for what seems to be 2 PIDs

Comment: You have to give it a specific session ID to disconnect.  Did you look at the examples in the link?