# PowerShell Spawn a background process for keep alive

Tags: powershell, background, spawn

I have a simple keep-alive function that will press ScrollLock every 60 seconds to stop my work laptop from going to sleep (altering power-management settings is not an option here as those settings are restricted to me on this work system), but this script is dependent upon the console that starts the function from always being open. Can someone advise how to get this function to:

• spawn a completely independent process (i.e. not a child process) that will continue to exist even after the console that runs the function closes?

• Make that new process completely silent i.e. starts invisibly as a background process that I can only see by running `Get-Process`?

Being able to create independent (non-child) processes in this way would be good for many other situations I think - that ability to create an independent process that does not close with the calling console would be really useful.

```
function KeepAlive {
    $wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    while($true) {
        $wsh.SendKeys('{SCROLLLOCK}')
        Start-Sleep 60
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately impossible in this case (why I mentioned "work" machine). I can alter some settings but I cannot change the power-management settings hence why asking this - in fact, this is pretty common on the vast majority of work systems that I've worked on).

Comment: I would recommend scrolllock not used anywhere but MS Excel  `$wsh.SendKeys('{SCROLLLOCK}')`

Comment: Willdo @Aaron, happy to change that to whatever you suggest. I guess I'm less worried about that, but *really* curious on how we might start it as a non-child process in the background.

Comment: You should take a look here as this is the way, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515359/how-can-i-start-a-background-job-in-powershell-that-outlives-its-parent

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way - use a background job:

```
Start-Job {
    $wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    while($true) {
        $wsh.SendKeys('{SCROLLLOCK}')
        Start-Sleep 60
    }
}
```

Background jobs will (transparently to you) result in the code running in a separate child process.

If you want to run your code in the background within the same process, you'll want to assign your code to run in a separate *runspace* - a runspace is somewhat analogous to a "thread" in low-level programming languages:

```
# Create (and open) a new runspace
$rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace([initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault2())
$rs.Open()

# Create a [powershell] object to bind our script to the above runspaces
$ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
    $wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    while($true) {
        $wsh.SendKeys('{SCROLLLOCK}')
        Start-Sleep 60
    }
})

# Tell powershell to run the code in the runspace we created
$ps.Runspace = $rs

# Invoke the code asynchronously
$handle = $ps.BeginInvoke()
```

The `BeginInvoke()` function will return immediately, and the code will start executing in our background runspace - meaning it doesn't block the default runspace, so you can continue using the shell in the mean time.

To end/halt execution again:

```
$ps.Stop()
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the goal of starting a process that is not a child process of the calling console? I'd like to be able to spawn something like this that is NOT dependent on that calling process (I think these answers are sub-processes of the calling process is that right?). I do really like this stuff though, I want to use runspaces etc so I'm going to experiment with this a lot thanks. Is there a way to get a function to spawn an independent non-child process though? Maybe scheduled tasks though it's far from simple and a mass of additional confusion.

Comment: @YorSubs why is it so important that it runs in a separate process that's not a child of the invoking process? What's your end goal here?

Comment: There are many tasks that I want to run independently of the calling console silently in the background. It's important to me as it is really frustrating that they are child processes that die when the console that the function is called from is exited. i.e. I would then be able to run some tasks that start at system startup that just work in the background doing what I need (without the added complexity of scheduled tasks). Child processes are great, but inconvenient for tasks that are wanted to run independently in the background.

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed that `Start-Process` seems to start a completely new process. I think this might be the correct approach. I guess that somehow I need to start a new powershell window, then get that process to run my code? A bit confused on the best approach here: should I take the Keypress code code and redirect it into a temp script file, and then call *that* script from the new `Start-Process` or is there a more efficient approach to do this do you think?