# How to not terminate a program when powershell exits?

Tags: powershell, notion

First, sorry for my poor english.

I'm beginner user at powershell.
I run programs using powershell CLI by registration enviroment variable.
Usally, There is no problem.
But When I run "NOTION" desktop application that will be closed when closed to powershell.
How to solve this problem?

```
PS C:\Users\User> notion
> Checking for update
> App starting with version 3.1.1 { system: 'win32 x64', electron: '28.0.0' }
> Sync version {
  assetsJsonPath: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Notion\\notionAssetCache-v2\\23.13.0.84\\assets.json',
  headersJsonPath: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Notion\\notionAssetCache-v2\\23.13.0.84\\headers.json'
}
> Child process running on 54760
> App is visible: true
> Update for version 3.1.1 is not available (latest version: 3.1.1, downgrade is disallowed).
```

I looked into powershell related documents.
But there are mosthow to write powershell script.

Comment: Please see if this line works: `Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName Win32_Process -MethodName "Create" -Arguments @{ CommandLine = "notion" }`

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47703806/19698859)

Comment: It is work.
I really thank you my benefactor.
I will check your link too!

Comment: ```Start-Process``` should work as well, fwiw.